# jQuery: display web page only after document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I load a web page inside document.ready I invoke an Ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    callAjaxFunction();

});
```

The effect is that the web page is first displayed with empty fields, and after the Ajax functions finishes the fields are populated. How to show the web page only after the Ajax function returns (show fields populated at once)?

Comment: `body{display:none}`...ajax callback...`$('body').show()`

Comment: What's the point of this versus rendering the initial state server side? I understand the data transfer will be a little heavy but it seems like the latency of an addition connection would be worse.

Comment: Load it from the server to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try hiding your whole document body first and then showing it with the ajax callback. Something like:

CSS:

```
body
{
  display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  callAjaxFunction();
});

function AjaxCallbackFunction() {
  //callback function code, populating fields
  $('body').show();
}
```

So once you have the ajax data, the page will be displayed with fields populated.

Comment: Gosh however did you come up with that answer (rolls eyes)

Comment: @j08691 I was really confused at first, but then I saw that you had commented this answer 12 minutes before I posted. Would it surprise you to know that sometimes people leave multiple pages open in multiple tabs and so they don't always see the most up-to-date versions? Also, if you had an answer, why not post it as an answer? That way the OP can choose your answer and the question gets marked as answered. I'm fairly new to posting here, so maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').hide();
$(function() {
    callAjaxFunction();
    $('body').show();
});
```

Comment: This would execute the `.show()` right after the ajax call was fired off as oppose to when the call returns and populates the data in the callback. I don't think this is the desired behavior. Move `$('body').show()` into `callAjaxFunction();`

Comment: Exactly. Or use a callback function to call the `$('body').show();` if callAjaxFunction() accept the callback function passing.